# Good things to know when developing a GUI architecture from scratch

Tags: user-interface, oop, architecture

What are best practices, tips, and general things to keep in mind for building an OOP GUI architecture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Know the important Design Patterns, such as MVC and its constituents like Observer.

Answer (score 2):

A good knowledge of Model-GUI-Mediator and MVP pattern could be' useful too.
Check www.danieleteti.it for an example about MVP (Passive View variant).

Answer (score 1):

As a part of what user367391 mentioned, you'll want to make sure business logic is encapsulated / packaged in such a way that it can be redeployed / reused in the event that there is a need to develop new clients on different platforms.